# document.querySelector('.header--input').value vs e.target.value

Tags: javascript

Why the following code does not log pressed keys in input box:

```
const input = document.querySelector('.header--input');
const inputValue = document.querySelector('.header--input').value;

input.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){

    if(inputValue !==''){
        console.log(inputValue);
    }
})
```

but the code below works:

```
const input = document.querySelector('.header--input');

input.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){

    const inputValue = e.target.value;
    if(inputValue !==''){
        console.log(inputValue);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first code does not work because `inputValue` is evaluated before the time your `keyup` is fired and the value is *empty* and that does not change on `keyup`. To get the current value of the input you have to assign the value inside the event handler function:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('.header--input');
input.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
  const inputValue = this.value;
  if(inputValue !==''){
    console.log(inputValue);
  }
});
```

```html
<input class="header--input">
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first code snippet, `inputValue` holds the initial value of `.header--input` input element, which won't change later.

In the second code, you are fetching the `updated input value`, whenever the key is pressed using `e.target.value;`.

Answer (score 0):

In your first method value of input is taken when the document is loaded which is `empty string` and it doesn't changes when keyup is called and your if condition always fails

```js
const input = document.querySelector('.header--input');
const inputValue = document.querySelector('.header--input').value;
console.log(inputValue, ' --> input value is empty')

input.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
    if(inputValue !==''){
        console.log(inputValue);
    }
})
```

```html
<input class='header--input'></input>
```

whereas in your second example value is evaluated on `keyup` event